# UIImage image from URL not being set

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I currently have a `UICollectionView` embed within a `UICollectionViewCell`, labels within the embbed the `embbedViewController` work properly but there's a problem with the `UIImageView`. For some strange reason I'm unable to set images from URL using AlamofireImage or Haneke but works properly when the image is set from a UIImage in `Image.xcassetts`. Would anyone be able to shed some light as to why this is happening?

**embbedCollectionView**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("trendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! customCollectionViewCell

        let imgUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: mainViewArrayContainer.artImg[indexPath.row])
        cell.secondCollectionViewImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(imgUrl)
        cell.secondCollectionViewLabel.text = mainViewArrayContainer.artImg[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

**ParentViewController**

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
         if (indexPath.row == 3){
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("trendingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
                    as! customCollectionViewCell

                let controller:EmbbedCollectionViewController = 
self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("embbedCollectionView") as! EmbbedCollectionViewController
                addChildViewController(controller)
                cell.addSubview(controller.view)
                return cell
            }
             else{
     //removed to save space

            }
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some strange reason I'm unable to set images from URL using AlamofireImage or Haneke

You cannot set the image directly by downloading. You must return the cell *now*. Downloading takes time. You have to download asynchronously and go back and set the image later.

Comment: also, when finish fetching images from asynchronous block, remember to ensure you are setting the images in a main queue.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. How can i ensure the images are being set in the main queue? @MatthewLuiHK

Comment: Just force to do it by using :         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in }